# Get set of edges

Tags: java, graph

I seem to have problem with using/understanding sets. In `JGraphT` there is a function `edgeSet()`. I would like to store all edges in the array, so I did this:

```
DefaultWeightedEdge edgesContained[]= (DefaultWeightedEdge[]) Graph.edgeSet().toArray(); //compiler returns this line as one with error
    for ( int i=0; i<=numberOfEdges; i++) {
    setRandomWeight(edgesContained[i], randomWeight());
    }
```

but the output that I get is

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lorg.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;*

Why is that and how should it look properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Graph.edgeSet().toArray()` will return a `Object[]`, which cannot be cast to `DefaultWeightedEdge[]`. Instead use `Graph.edgeSet().toArray(new DefaultWeightedEdge[0])`.